# Jmeter Recording of scripts behind Proxy

Tags: proxy, jmeter

I need to perform JMETER TEST and Record a WEB Login Page, my company is behind the proxy. If I change the proxy and port of the Firefox to 8080, My Application doesn't launch.

If I don't change the proxy in Firefox, Then the recorder doesn't record the script.

I tried with IE, Where due to corporate policy, I cant change the policy and it is disabled.

How I get out of this situation?

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep Firefox proxy settings to point to JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder), i.e. server name should be `localhost`, port should be `8888`

In its turn JMeter needs to be configured to use your corporate proxy, it can be done in 2 ways:

1. Via command-line parameters, like:

   ```
   jmeter -H your_corporate_proxy_host -P your_corporate_proxy_port -n -t ...
   ```

   this way the change will be applied only once
2. If you want the changes to be permanent you can add the following lines to *system.properties* file (located in the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   http.proxyHost=your_corporate_proxy_host
   http.proxyPort=your_corporate_proxy_port
   https.proxyHost=your_corporate_proxy_host
   https.proxyPort=your_corporate_proxy_port
   ```

References:

- [Using JMeter behind a proxy](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html)
- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)